# Div overflow issue (HTML, CSS)

Tags: html, css

```
<div id="broadcast">
<div class="broadcast_element">
 <div class="broadcast_username"><?php echo $row[0]?>:</div>
 <div class="broadcast_broadcast"><?php echo $row[2];?></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Simplified CSS:

```
.broadcast_element
{
 width: 100%;
}
\#broadcast
{
 width: 200px;
}
```

The problem is: The php script echoes the data in a straight line causing it to the overflow from the div (broadcast).
word wrap: I hate IE, so no way i'm using that.
overflow: the properties do not provide what i want to achieve.

**The question simply - I'm looking for a solution that'll solve this overflow problem once and for all. I'm looking for something general i can apply in any similar case.**

My thoughts - Being a noob the only way i can think of is using javascript to insert a `<br/>` after every 200px of data? I know thats sad :P.

Thank You.

Comment: Do you want the data that overflow to be hidden?

Comment: Oh, i had no idea of that, Think i'll have to register to do that. Cheerios, i'll do it asap.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try those CSS properties :

- [White-space](http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_text_white-space.asp)
- [Word-wrap](http://www.css3.com/css-word-wrap/)
- [Overflow: hidden](http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_pos_overflow.asp)

Comment: I quote your original post: **word wrap: I hate IE, so no way i'm using that.** - ? implying you *didn't* want to use word wrap?

Comment: He may want to talk about the php function?